# QuickChick "Error: Could not compile mli file"

Tags: emacs, coq, opam

I successfully installed **coq 8.9.1** and **coq-quickchick 1.1.0 with opam 2.0.4** and I'm programming on **emacs 26.1**.

However, when running a QuickChick command I received the following error:

> Error: Could not compile mli file

Any ideas of what I can do?

Also, I have tried to include the following command before the QuickChick command:
"QuickChickDebug Debug On."

Still, no success and no instructive message was provided.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to manually extract and compile.

A first idea is to replace `QuickChick my_prop.` with `Extraction TestCompile my_prop.`, which will also try to compile.

There is also `Separate Extraction my_prop.` (assuming `my_prop` is an identifier), which just outputs `.ml` files so you can compile them by hand and see what is wrong.

There are other variants of extraction worth knowing about:

https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/addendum/extraction.html#generating-ml-code

Answer (score 1):

Can you compile the file from command line? If you can, you can open emacs from the command line and re-run and see.

BTW, what's your OS? I have the same problem on OS X Catalina and the problem comes from the privacy policy of Catalina I guess.